# How to set some identity for a specific time in TOR?

Tags: tor

When I am running TOR browser it gets me a new IP when I open a new tab. 
But I want to select IP by changing New Identity and stay on it for some time - how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must customize torrc config with this string -

ExitNodes $fingerprint,$fingerprint,...

Details - https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit